# Transparent proxy in Haskell

Tags: haskell, metaprogramming, rpc

In many languages there are ways to create something called transparent proxy (or transproxy) for doing RPC or even calling SQL functions. In C# for example we can both use meta-programming (using IOC) or DLR for doing so. Is there any way in Haskell for creating a transparent proxy? Suppose we have some service and after creating the proxy variable we must be able to call 'myFunc' as below:

```
proxy myFunc arg1 arg2
```

or whatever similar. Do I have to use Template Haskell for this?

Comment: If you're talking about, eg, [`DynamicProxy`](http://www.castleproject.org/projects/dynamicproxy/) then no, Haskell doesn't have anything as ugly as that horrible hack. Ideas that you learned in Language X often won't be applicable to Language Y because Language Y has a different way of doing things. So, what are you really trying to achieve?

Comment: I certainly know about paradigm difference between languages since I have seriously worked with a half-dozen languages. I do the same with Python using __getattr__ and __call__ magic methods and in C# using IoC Proxy object. I know there is no similar way in Haskell to do that but I mean is there any alternative to implement client transparency in Haskell? (Other than full code generation)

Comment: Some initial workaround can be defining a typeclass for the service and then an operator for flipping first argument of function so that the resulting invokation seems prettier:

    `x .> f = f x

    class MyService where 
        myFunc :: MyService -> a  -> b -> Int

    result <- myServiceInstance .> myFunc arg1 arg2`

Comment: If you're somewhat familiar with Haskell, you'll know that it always makes side-effects explicit. So you'll never call a web-service or db outside `IO`...

Comment: @mb21 I know that and that is why I have called the service using a monad notaion <- plz get  more accurate before complain

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way is to just pass the proxy as an argument instead of the other way round (most of the time I just do that, and the proxy is just a handle for a database connection)
You could also define something like this:

```
newtype Proxy = Proxy {withProxy :: (forall a . Proxiable a -> IO a)}
```

But I don't think it would really simplify anything.

Comment: It may not simplify, but at least beautifies the code! Thanks anyway!